# Tailwind is working partially (React + Tailwind)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

Really, I can't find the problem because for the same div some classes are working and some are not.
I tried to find some clues but most users didn't have paths in the tailwind config file.

**My code:**

[image]

`fixed` is working fine, but `bottom-2` and `right-4` aren't. Actually, I don't know if `w-[405px]` is working.

Comment: If you are using tailwind 3 you might be using the "just in time" compiler which only adds the classes you are using.

So it might be that tailwind can't find these classes and wont add them to the compiled css.

You need to add the paths to your files where you use tailwind classes in your tailwind.config.js like this

content: [
    './path/to/view/files/**/*.fileExtention',
  ],

Comment: Make sure you are using the steps outlined here for **Using PostCSS:** https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss and not for **Using CLI.** The former is more suitable for working with frameworks using build tools like Webpack to bundle files, **such as React**. The latter is a more direct setup for vanilla Node projects and frameworks using a simple Node setup to compile Tailwind CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Add `mode: 'jit',` to your tailwind.config.js in order `w-[405px]` works. I think other classes is working you just didn't noticed it or maybe conflict on other styles in your div.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [vimesh style](https://github.com/vimeshjs/vimesh-style). It watches all html element class attribute changes and generate tailwind compatible css at runtime. Just add

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vimesh/style"></script>
```

at the head of your page.

Answer (score 0):

We use tailwind at work, not something I'm super in love with but if we're adding tailwind classes that haven't been used in the document yet we have to do it locally for the compiler to add the new classes to your document.

Unsure if this is the only way to do it as its fairly new to us, but if you bring your project to a local environment and use the command

```
npm run watch
```

it will signal to tailwind to watch your class names and add the new ones to the compiled list. so if your making custom ones using [] its likely that tailwind hasn't addded those instances to the minified version of their css

Answer (score -1):

For real I dont find how to resolve it. But in my case I just added the same classes to component and after it tailwind started to see it. If someone knows why exact its happening Im still waiting for any ideas